# Devise - Login with email and cast_id

Tags: scope

I need do an user login using the email and cast_id. this is my code:

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
            :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, request_keys: [:cast]

    belongs_to :cast

    def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
        where(:email => warden_conditions[:email], :cast => warden_conditions[:cast]).first
    end
end
```

**Sing In View**

```
<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :cast, value: @cast.id.to_s %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

In the initializer i added

```
config.request_keys = [:cast]
```

I followed this tutorial https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain

But this error is show

```
undefined method `cast' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x007f17780feab0>

 def request_values
    keys = request_keys.respond_to?(:keys) ? request_keys.keys : request_keys
    values = keys.map { |k| self.request.send(k) }
    Hash[keys.zip(values)]
  end
```

Comment: whats the devise version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to modify your warden_conditions to this:

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    where(:email => warden_conditions[:email], :cast_id => warden_conditions[:cast]).first
end
```

If you don't have success try to another approach

## user.rb

```ruby
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
 :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, authentication_keys:{email:true, login:false, cast_id:true}
```

```ruby
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)     
  where(:email => warden_conditions[:email], :cast_id => warden_conditions[:cast_id]).first
end
```

## view

```html
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :cast_id, value: @cast.id %>
</div>
```